# Apache/Passenger error: cannot load such file -- rails_extensions (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, passenger-apache

I receive the following error when attempting to run a rails application with Apache, Passenger, and rbenv. I'm able to run it just fine with `rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e production`, but when running under Passenger I get the following error:

```
Error: The application encountered the following error: cannot load such file -- rails_extensions (LoadError)
    /home/deploy/reservations/config/environment.rb:4:in `require'
    /home/deploy/reservations/config/environment.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    config.ru:4:in `require'
    config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    /home/deploy/reservations/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `instance_eval'
    /home/deploy/reservations/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:125:in `initialize'
    config.ru:1:in `new'
    config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:390:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
    /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Here are my environment variables:

```
USER = deploy
SHLVL = 0
HOME = /home/deploy
WSGI_ENV = production
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
APACHE_RUN_DIR = /var/run/apache2
APPLICATION_HOST = 192.168.178.28
APACHE_PID_FILE = /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
LOGNAME = deploy
JOURNAL_STREAM = 8:74225
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.48 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.10
RACK_ENV = production
RBENV_SHELL = bash
PATH = /home/deploy/reservations/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
INVOCATION_ID = f18dc46d76e34048a133e8525756b5d2
STORAGE_LOCATION = local
APACHE_LOCK_DIR = /var/lock/apache2
LANG = C
PASSENGER_SPAWN_WORK_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXngFNha
RES_SMTP_AUTH = true
SHELL = /bin/bash
IN_PASSENGER = 1
NODE_PATH = /usr/share/passenger/node
APACHE_RUN_GROUP = www-data
APACHE_RUN_USER = www-data
APACHE_LOG_DIR = /var/log/apache2
RAILS_ENV = production
RAILS_HOST_NAME = 192.168.178.28
PWD = /home/deploy/reservations
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES = false
XDG_DATA_DIRS = /usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = production
NODE_ENV = production
BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLE_BIN_PATH = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLE_GEMFILE = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLER_ORIG_MANPATH = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_BUNDLER_VERSION = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_GEM_HOME = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_GEM_PATH = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_MANPATH = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_PATH = /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
BUNDLER_ORIG_RB_USER_INSTALL = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_RUBYLIB = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
BUNDLER_ORIG_RUBYOPT = BUNDLER_ENVIRONMENT_PRESERVER_INTENTIONALLY_NIL
GEM_PATH = 
GEM_HOME = /home/deploy/reservations/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0
BUNDLE_BIN_PATH = /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle
BUNDLE_GEMFILE = /home/deploy/reservations/Gemfile
BUNDLER_VERSION = 1.17.3
RUBYOPT = -rbundler/setup
RUBYLIB = /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib
MANPATH = /home/deploy/reservations/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/unicorn-5.1.0/man
```

and Apache config vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName 192.168.178.28

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/deploy/reservations/public

        SetEnv STORAGE_LOCATION local
        SetEnv RAILS_HOST_NAME 192.168.178.28
        SetEnv APPLICATION_HOST 192.168.178.28
        SetEnv RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES false
        SetEnv RES_SMTP_AUTH true

        PassengerDisableAnonymousTelemetry on
        PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby
        PassengerAppRoot /home/deploy/reservations
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        RailsEnv production
        PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on

    <Directory /home/deploy/reservations/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      # Uncomment this if you're on Apache > 2.4:
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I really appreciate any tips for finding what the problem could be! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any additional info in logs? There may be a more verbose error that will more easily pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Update: 

Commenting out `require 'rails_extensions'` from `/home/deploy/reservations/config/environment.rb` seems to fix it, and doesn't look to cause any further problems. But I'm still very confused as to why this causes an error with Passenger, but no errors are to be seen in any logs when starting the application with `rails s`. Any ideas?